# Can you reset the nether?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Im new to minecraft . I finally got into the nether and was disapointed. I could not find a nether fortress . Can i reset the nether? If i can please let me know. Im on Pc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't reset the nether, but there are some tricks for finding Nether fortresses.

From the [Minecraft Wiki article for Nether Fortresses](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Nether_fortress#Spawning):

> Nether fortress tend to cluster together in strips that run north and south. When you're searching for your first nether fortress, traveling east or west will give you the best chances of running into one. If you travel north or south, you could travel a long distance between two strips of fortresses. But if you have already found a fortress, you should travel either north or south to find another, which will likely be within a few hundred blocks. Note that north and south spawning is just a tendency and you may not find additional fortresses simply by going north and south from a located fortress in every case. Be flexible in your search and note that additional fortresses may still be east or west from a located fortress.

You can see which direction you're traveling by pressing F3.

Comment: There are also tools for finding nether fortresses given a world seed. Try chunkbase.com.

Answer (score 18):

To answer your question, you *can* reset the nether, but the new one that will generate will be the same as the old one, except without any changes you may have made. (This could be used to cheat, go to the nether, gather resources, reset the nether, gather the same resources in the same location, and so on…)
To reset the nether, go to

```
C:\Users\<your windows username>\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\saves\New World
```

on Windows or

```
~/Library/Application Support/minecraft
```

on OS X.
Next go to the "/saves" folder, and then into the folder that corresponds with the world in which you want to reset the nether. Usually the folder will have the same name as the world it corresponds with. Finally go to the "/DIM-1" folder and delete anything inside. Next time you enter the nether, minecraft will reset the nether to how it was before you made any changes to it.

Note: This answers the question "how to reset the nether", but this just erases any changes you may have made to it, thus "reset". You can't really use this to find nether fortresses.

Comment: Thanks. For actual servers, delete the content in: `WORLD_NAME/dim-1` within your server directory.

Comment: Btw: The respawned nether was not the same as we had before. :/ + there is a new block now, Magma Block or similar to that. We didn't have that one before. :)

Comment: It is probably different becouse of changes to the world generator in newer updates ;)

Comment: This was the answer I was looking for, because a power outage caused the nether chunks to be corrupted.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot reset the nether without making a new world.

There always are nether fortresses in the nether so keep looking. I would install a mini-map mod so you can way point your portal so you can venture further without the worry of loosing your portal. Perhaps the morph mod or another mod so it can allow you to fly so you can travel faster.

Do note that they can be affected by the `Generate Structures` option, so make sure that's on (It's on by default.)

Comment: Make sure you are using a version of minecraft that have fortresses though.

Comment: @Skye do not signal your edits in the text. Contrary to most other websites, Arqade (and SE in general) has a full revision history (click on "edited X ago"), so it's not needed.

Comment: I think you can reset the nether using things like mc edit, but the seed won't change

Answer (score 1):

Resetting the nether won't change the position of fortresses, as they are based on the seed which you cannot change without messing other things up. You can use some tools on the internet that show you the exact position of all the fortresses.

I would recommend Amidst: https://github.com/toolbox4minecraft/amidst/releases

Or if you don't want to install something to your computer, here's a handy online tool (be sure to read the "How To Use" section at the bottom): http://chunkbase.com/apps/nether-fortress-finder

Answer (score 0):

You can actually reset the nether. Make a new world in creative and go into the nether. If it has a fortress then leave the nether, exit the game then go to C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming.minecraft\saves then click on the creative world that you created then go to DIM-1 folder copy the contents then move them to your survival world or any other world. Make sure the world you are moving it into you delete all of the contents in the DIM-1 folder.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, yes you can, in your settings of your world you can find two options (reset nether) and (reset end) you can try looking for those two buttons